# Type or namespace could not be found, not client profile issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

I am trying to create a web application. It runs fine on localhost but I keep running into this error when I try it on the test server. I have looked through other questions off and on for a few days and tried all kinds of solutions but still no luck with the error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'courseDBLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 6:  using System.Diagnostics;
Line 7:  using System.Collections;
Line 8:  using courseDBLibrary;
Line 9:  
Line 10: public partial class Charts : System.Web.UI.Page
```

courseDBLibrary is the namespace in a referenced dll file. The dll contains 2 separate c#  files, each with their own class, under the same namespace. The dll was added through the add reference dialog.

Originally the dll is placed in the bin at the root of the project, but when putting it on the server I have moved the bin folder to the wwwroot folder.

Finally, the dll is **not** using the client profile framework(aka is using .NET Framework 3.5)

The files in the DLL look like this

```
namespace courseDBLibrary {
  public class class1 {
    ..
```

and

```
namespace courseDBLibrary {
  public class class2 {
    ..
```

The file that throws the error is a fairly complex aspx file with c# code behind but, as you can see, the compiler is not even reaching the class part.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly  in the web.config?

Comment: I don't think you can separate/move your bin folder from the project.  Does it run properly if your bin is under project directory?

Comment: Can you right click on your project file and open it in notepad, then look for the particular entry for dll containing courseDBLibrary. Verify that the path matches the actual path on disk

Comment: Vlad, no it doesn't work when the bin is under the project directory.    Earlz, the dll is not strongly named, but attempting it anyway gave the 'could not load file or assembly error'

Comment: What project file should I be looking for? It is a website so there is no sln file.